# iframe shrinking parent page in iPhone's Safari

Tags: wordpress, mobile, iframe, mobile-safari

I'm using an iframe to display external webpages on my WordPress site. It looks great on desktops, but on my iphone the embedded page seems to break the parent page causing in to squish over to one side.

Here's an example:
http://www.torontoactingstudios.com/studios/bongo-productions/

I've tried restricting the size of the iframe for mobile devices, but then the page I'm importing no longer shrinks to fit the iphone screen.

Would love to hear any ideas...

===

Well I ended up basically coming up with a different mobile version of the pages with the frame. Not the perfect solution, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i think there is no "clean" way solving this. At first, responsive design & iframes don't play together well. Second, iPhones and iframes don't play together well as well.

Maybe the best idea for you is to serve a different layout for mobile via a mobile redirect plugin. I.E. this one: [Simple Mobile URL Redirect Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-mobile-url-redirect/)

Comment: would you mind accepting my answer if it was right for you? Thanks alot!